# Running Python script continously 24/7 on the cloud

Tags: python, cloud, hosting

Is there any solution for my needs? 
Basically, I'm running the script that runs a certain function with APScheduler. 
So the script will run a function every 5 minutes.

PythonAnywhere can't do that because they don't support the APScheduler.. And it's very bad practice if we use an infinite loop on PythonAnywhere.

Comment: since you're going to run it on a periodic basis (and not just schedule at arbitrary time), did you consider setting up a cronjob?

Answer (score 3):

You can try **Heroku** and its [Worker Dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing).

I found it much simple to set up than other services like AWS or Google Cloud Platform. You can have a basic account for free and play around.

They have as add-on [Heroku Scheduler](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/scheduler), which would allow you to avoid the infinite `while`.

> **Heroku Scheduler**
>
> Run scheduled tasks every 10 minutes, every hour, or
>   every day. Starting at $0/mo.
>
> ***Run Jobs with Ease***
>
> Scheduler is an add-on for running jobs on your app at scheduled time
>   intervals, much like cron in a traditional server environment.

Comment: the heroku is going to turn off free dynos :((

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with either a cronjob or a helper script inside an infinite while loop.

In option 1, you would type in `crontab -e` and you would setup a cronjob. Once in the cron editor, you can set the frequency for various frequencies. For a 5 minute cronjob this code should work

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/yourscript.py
```

For option 2, you would setup some variation of the command below as a python script

```
import time
......

while True:
# your function
   function()
   sleep(300)
```

The sleep command will pause execution for 5 minutes.

I would caution you that running an infinite `while` loop on PythonAnywhere will quickly burn through your CPU time allocation (depends on how efficient code you write).